# Is it possible to retrieve the results of a console command for a remote website?

Tags: javascript, python, php, web, curl

For example:

If I go to https://www.yahoo.com, enter the following console command within any browser console:

`localStorage.length`

I would get:
`2`

Is it possible to accomplish above with any scripting languages?

Pseudocode:  (I am using curl here, but I did not see any options to execute console command in any curl documentation, so this is probably incorrect)

```
    curl ("https://wwww.yahoo.com");  // establish connection to a remote site
    curl (execute console command: "localStorage.length" );  // execute console command like you would on the yahoo site
    echo (display results);  // which should be "2" in this example
    curl close;
```

Comment: `curl` wouldn't run any JavaScript code. It just asks the server for a resource and gives it to you - it will not and *cannot* execute scripts on the page or similar.

Comment: You could use something like https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a "[headless browser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Headless_browser)" kind of tool that allows you to script interactions, [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) or similar. These are tools that behave just like web browsers, they just don't have any UI. So you can have them navigate to a page, and then you can run code as though it were running on that page.